# Out of memory causes debugging to freeze?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, memory-management

On a server (with 1GiB of memory) I'm running SQL Server, IIS7, and my application (running in debug on the VS IDE). SQL Server had not been configured to have a maximum memory usage, and so it was growing and growing until memory contention started kicking in. When memory was tight, my application seemed to (very rarely) just **freeze**. It never crashed, no errors, nothing, just completely **frozen**.

Each time I connected with remote desktop, and hit the **pause** button in the debugger (to examine the stack trace) everything would look fine, and upon **unpausing**, the application would resume (and **unfreeze**) as if nothing ever happened.

Today I **unfroze** the server doing this, and in my logs found it had been in a frozen state for over half an hour (literally doing nothing):

> 1/3/2013 7:37:07 PM [LOG] A realtime constraint was violated; 2197516ms was required to process sector AI.

Is this behavior documented anywhere? I like that the debugger can just freeze the application rather than throwing an out-of-memory exception, but I'd like to know about this (like what circumstances allow the debugger to do this, since out-of-memory exceptions do exist!).

**Edit:** Just to be crystal clear on this, my application is not showing any signs of a memory leak; it has been running for **56 days** now, and barely using **50MiB** of memory. When I unfreeze the application, things just go back to normal running, I have not restarted the application in nearly two months. Configuring [SQL Server Maximum Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx) (common practice when SQL Server is not running alone) will likely make this issue disappear, but as stated originally, I want to know more about it.

Comment: No **visible** errors. It's safe to say you have a memory leak, yes? I would focus on that.

Comment: It's not a memory leak, the application has ran for **56 days** without showing any increase in memory usage. SQL Server is the only process that grows concerningly large in memory usage. and when SQL Server grows large, my application (which is using barely even 50MB of memory) freezes, and IIS's database connections start failing with time-outs (even despite time-outs being explicitly disabled).

Comment: I think the real question is why are you trying to run IIS and SQL on a server with such a small amount of memory?

Comment: Despite of this choice, it is already stated @Mr.Smith knows how to solve the problem. I'm not sure whether VS is the best debugger for memory issues. Sincs everything is running on a single system, I think in case of truly running out of memory, it is not surprising everthing freezes, including the debugging (since VS is not a small program). Doesn't looking at the task manager give you enough info about which process is taking what amount of memory and how much memory you have left?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger SQL Server Express requires little more than 128MB of RAM to run on a 64bit OS, and IIS 7 defaults to a maximum of about 12 concurrent users (without editing registry keys).

Comment: @LeonNewswanger Left unconstrained (on a 64bit OS), SQL Server will grow to consume around 90% of a system's memory. People with 64GiB of RAM are often surprised to find SQL Server consuming over 48GiB of it.

Comment: Yes but minimum system requirements are rarely enough to actually make use of SQL for all intensive purposes. I have instances of SQL server I use at work that often use 3+ GB of memory.

Comment: Also OutOfMemoryException is thrown when your application is out of memory, not your system. An OutOfMemoryException doesn't necessarily indicate that you've run out of system memory. Try reading this article to see if it helps you gain any insight into the issues. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: @LeonNewswanger +1 for a link to **Eric Lippert**'s blog; I love his articles. I designed my pathfinding code around his (though ported down to .NET 2.0).

Comment: The comments in the article talk more in depth about the CLR and memory usage in .Net as well. May be helpful. And Eric Lippert has been a lifesaver for me at work.